# NestJs - Class library

Tags: node.js, nestjs, class-library

I am using nestjs to build several small applications, in doing so I would quite like a class library in which all projects can reference to pass the classes from one project to another if they'd like to, or at least standardise the objects to a contract they must adhere to.

Is there a way to approach this where I have a single standalone collection of simplistic domain classes not bound to a specific nestjs project, without specific domain logic involved, moreover the structure of how something should look as opposed to what it does?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a perfect use case for using a [`NestJS Monorepo` with a library](https://docs.nestjs.com/cli/libraries), or to use something like [`Nx`](https://nx.dev) and use a library from there. In both cases, you're creating a reusable set of code (usually interfaces or classes) to be used throughout different parts of your servers/applications.

Comment: I really appreciate that, however the application will be distributed and a monorepo is not an option, is there a way to create a library and set it up as an npm package?

Comment: Yeah, you can publish a package of classes that are essentially just to be used as common types.